# Connecting to Database using powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, windows-server, sql-server-2017

I'm trying to connect to my `database` using `PowerShell` but it's not find it even though I can see it using SSMS.

[image]

I'm trying to follow the example MS provides [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/tasks/creating-altering-and-removing-databases#creating-altering-and-removing-a-database-in-powershell)

Comment: Hi, Welcome to the site. Please post your code as text instead of screenshots. Also, you're just not following the examples are you? The examples you linked to create a database and nowhere do they ask you to type `localhost` at the prompt.

Comment: I was just testing what would happen if I typed localhost. The other lines are pretty much what the example is -_-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are on the SQL Server where the database resides, then you can follow these steps to connect to a database in **PowerShell**

First you have to load the **SQL Server PowerShell Module**. This is achieved with the following simple command:

```
PS C:\> sqlps
Microsoft (R) SQL Server (R) PowerShell
Version 12.0.5557.0
Copyright (c) 2014 Microsoft. All rights reserved.

PS SQLSERVER:\>
```

You have now loaded the SQL Powershell Module and have been switched to the **SQLSERVER** drive.

Let's see what we can retrieve from the system:

```
PS SQLSERVER:\> get-childitem

Name            Root                           Description
----            ----                           -----------
DAC             SQLSERVER:\DAC                 SQL Server Data-Tier Application
                                               Component
DataCollection  SQLSERVER:\DataCollection      SQL Server Data Collection
SQLPolicy       SQLSERVER:\SQLPolicy           SQL Server Policy Management
Utility         SQLSERVER:\Utility             SQL Server Utility
SQLRegistration SQLSERVER:\SQLRegistration     SQL Server Registrations
SQL             SQLSERVER:\SQL                 SQL Server Database Engine
SSIS            SQLSERVER:\SSIS                SQL Server Integration Services
XEvent          SQLSERVER:\XEvent              SQL Server Extended Events
DatabaseXEvent  SQLSERVER:\DatabaseXEvent      SQL Server Extended Events
SQLAS           SQLSERVER:\SQLAS               SQL Server Analysis Services


PS SQLSERVER:\>
```

That looks promising.

We'll switch into the **SQL Server Database Engine** (SQL) and see what we have:

```
PS SQLSERVER:\> cd SQL
PS SQLSERVER:\SQL> get-childitem

MachineName
-----------
SQLSERVER-NAME
```

Ok. Let's connect to the `SQLSERVER-NAME` instance and carry on researching (I used `localhost` in my example, because I am on the server itself):

```
PS SQLSERVER:\SQL> cd localhost
PS SQLSERVER:\SQL\localhost> get-childitem

Instance Name
-------------
DEFAULT
```

Switch to the DEFAULT instance:

```
PS SQLSERVER:\SQL\localhost> cd DEFAULT
PS SQLSERVER:\SQL\localhost\DEFAULT>
```

And retrieve a list of instance objects:

```
PS SQLSERVER:\SQL\localhost\DEFAULT> get-childitem
Audits
AvailabilityGroups
BackupDevices
Credentials
CryptographicProviders
Databases
Endpoints
JobServer
Languages
LinkedServers
Logins
Mail
ResourceGovernor
Roles
ServerAuditSpecifications
SystemDataTypes
SystemMessages
Triggers
UserDefinedMessages
PS SQLSERVER:\SQL\localhost\DEFAULT>
```

Ok, switch into the databases...

```
PS SQLSERVER:\SQL\localhost\DEFAULT> cd Databases
PS SQLSERVER:\SQL\localhost\DEFAULT\Databases> get-childitem

Name                 Status          Containment Type Recovery Model CompatLvl Collation                      Owner
----                 ------          ---------------- -------------- --------- ---------                      -----
AdminDB2             Normal          None             Full                 120 Latin1_General_CS_AS           sa
AdventureWorks2012   Normal          None             Simple               110 SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS   sa
File_Types           Normal          None             Full                 120 Latin1_General_CS_AS           sa
ReportServer         Normal          None             Full                 120 Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS     sa
ReportServerTempDB   Normal          None             Simple               120 Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS     sa
sqlnexus             Normal          None             Full                 120 Latin1_General_CS_AS           sa
StackExchange        Normal          None             Full                 120 Latin1_General_CS_AS           sa
TestDatabase2FS      Normal          None             Full                 120 Latin1_General_CS_AS           sa


PS SQLSERVER:\SQL\localhost\DEFAULT\Databases>
```

Once you are in the correct database, you can then set of relevant CMD-lets.

```
PS SQLSERVER:\SQL\localhost\DEFAULT\Databases> cd StackExchange
PS SQLSERVER:\SQL\localhost\DEFAULT\Databases\StackExchange> cd Tables
PS SQLSERVER:\SQL\localhost\DEFAULT\Databases\StackExchange\Tables> Get-ChildItem

Schema                       Name                           Created
------                       ----                           -------
dbo                          Blocking                       05.04.2017 16:17
dbo                          deadlock1                      10.01.2017 16:09
dbo                          deadlock2                      10.01.2017 16:09
dbo                          Issue_776                      29.05.2017 07:54
dbo                          Q184469_Customer               28.08.2017 10:29
dbo                          Q184469_DVD                    28.08.2017 10:29
dbo                          Q184469_DVD_Purchase           28.08.2017 10:29
dbo                          Q190497_Stats_Hash             09.11.2017 09:06
dbo                          Reference_Questions            06.01.2017 15:07
dbo                          Täble_Name                     18.12.2017 11:53
dbo                          tblTable                       30.08.2017 10:45
dbo                          TestJohnNessDBATemp            12.09.2017 11:58
DBT                          Application                    08.02.2017 07:59
DBT                          Database                       08.02.2017 08:02
DBT                          Instance                       08.02.2017 07:57
DBT                          Server                         08.02.2017 07:54
DBT                          User                           08.02.2017 08:00


PS SQLSERVER:\SQL\localhost\DEFAULT\Databases\StackExchange\Tables>
```

You can then carry on from here.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I'm not sure why the examples provided by MS don't explain that you need to be in SQLPS. Very detailed explication.

Comment: @Batman `sqlps.exe` (which is not the SQL Server PowerShell module) is a weird, stuck-at-an-old-version partially-implemented version of PowerShell. IMHO no one should be using it. There is a `slqps`  PowerShell module, but it has numerous problems, does not get any updates from Microsoft, and was superseded by the `sqlserver` module several years ago. Just use regular PowerShell and then `import-module sqlserver;`

Answer (score -1):

Just follow the simple steps as mention below

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | out-null 

$srv = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') "LOCALHOST"  


#This sets the connection to mixed-mode authentication 

$srv.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure=$false; 



#This sets the login name 
$srv.ConnectionContext.set_Login("userid"); 



#This sets the password 
$srv.ConnectionContext.set_Password("PaSSw0rd")
```

we can retrieve the list of databases running on the SQL Server instance by adding the code below.

```
$srv.Databases | Select name
```

How to run i am also attaching a screen shot to you

[image]

**Get-Credentials login through PowerShell**

In PowerShell Type

```
>Get-Credential
```

[image]
For further reference please read the article [Connect to SQL Server via Windows PowerShell with SQL Server authentication](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1947/connect-to-sql-server-via-windows-powershell-with-sql-server-authentication/)

Comment: We normally ask people with questions to post code instead of screen shots, which aren't always available when working in a corporate environment. Could you consider adding code instead of screen shots in your answer?

Comment: @hot2use, I agree with you but sometimes it required for better understanding to OP. Because as per OP powershell i saw , he has committed some mistakes.